# using Task.WhenAll and Linq Select new object

Tags: c#, linq, .net-6.0

I'm trying to figure it there is a way to use `Task.WhenAll` when constructing anonymous objects in linq. I'm using .net 6.

The vanilla case would look like this, and this works

```
var taskList = dataSource.Select(d => _client.GetAsync(d.Id));
var taskListResult = await Task.WhenAll(taskList);
```

I am however trying to construct an object inside the select decorating it with additional properties.

```
var taskList = dataSource
        .Select(d => new 
        {
            ClientResult = _client.GetAsync(d.Id),
            Id = d.Id,
            OtherProperty = d.Other
        });

var taskListResult = await Task.WhenAll(taskList);
```

Is there some way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: `.Select(async d => new { ClientResult = await _client.GetAsync(d.Id), .... })`. The `async` lambda will return a `Task<Anonymous Type>`, which get collected up by the `Select` and awaited by the `Task.WhenAll`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `async`-`await` in the statement lambda which will make it an [`async` one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions#async-lambdas):

```cs
var taskList = dataSource
        .Select(async d => new 
        {
            ClientResult = await _client.GetAsync(d.Id),
            Id = d.Id,
            OtherProperty = d.Other
        });

var taskListResult = await Task.WhenAll(taskList);
```